# Exponent operation over element of G

Tags: pairings, abe

I found a definition of an exponent operation over the element of $\mathbb{G}$ in this [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6382815) (page 4):

$$ (g^a)^{\% b} = g ^{a \text{ mod } b}$$

I couldn't understand the rest of the paper (Decrypt primitive).

We have $D = g^r g^{M_S} = g^{r + M_S}$

How could they compute: $(D)^{\% M_T}$. In this paper, they have written it in a form:

$$(D)^{\% M_T} = g^{(r + M_S) \text{ mod } M_T}$$

But the exponentiation in $D$ is already computed, we cannot run the $\text{ mod }$ operator before the exponentiation.

Here are captures of the paper:

[image: Setup - Encrypt]
[image: KeyGen - Decrypt]
[image: Decrypt (continuation and end)]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The paper is behind a login/paywall, so I cannot read it, so this is simply a guess. If $(r + M_S)$ is known then $(D)^{\%M_T}$ can be computed. If $(r + M_S) < M_T$ then it is already reduced. Otherwise, compute $(D)g^{-kM_T}$ where $kM_T$ is the largest multiple of $M_T \leq (r + M_S)$.

Comment: @user13741 I added some captures from the paper. $(r + M_S)$ is not known, because the exponentation is already computed during the keyGen primitive.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $M_T$ is the order of $g$, then it's real easy to compute $(D)^{\%M_T}$: it's the value $D$.

That is, if $M_T$ is the order of $g$, then we have the identity $g^x = g^{x \bmod M_T}$ for any $x$, and in particular, $g^{r + M_S} = g^{(r + M_S) \bmod M_T}$.

The paper is just noting that the $\bmod$ operation happens implicitly here.

BTW: I've never seen the notation $(g^a)^{\%b}$ before; I don't believe that's very standard...

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by $M_T$ is the order of $g$. I edited my question by adding some captures from the paper. I think that $(r + M_S)$ is not known, it is computed in $D$. Yes, the notation $ (g ^ a) ^ { \% b } $ is not standard, it was just defined by authors to simplify formulas

Comment: I don't believe $M_\mathcal{T}$ is the order of $g$ or $\mathbb{G}$. [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4qCEh.png) might help.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have already read what you shared in the capture and I still don't understand how they could compute $D^{\% M_T}$, as the value of $D$ is provided to the user as an element from $G_2$ and not in a form of formula !

Comment: @poncho But in their scheme they have to eliminate $M_S$. They take advantage from the fact that $M_S \text{ mod } M_T = 0$,  so $M_S$ will desappear in the exponent ! My question is, if I want implement this scheme, how could I implement this operation?